# In Win 7, how to arrange videos in a folder in a specific order so they load in VLC player in the right order?

Tags: windows-7

How do I put videos in the order I want them in within a folder? I even tried opening a new folder and cutting + pasting the videos individually in the order I want them but they go out of order anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could try renaming them...  Put 001 in front of the first video you want to play, 002 in front of the 2nd, etc., then sort by name.

Comment: So, there's no other way? Because the videos are episodes so they are numbered but when I exit the folder and enter it again...the videos rearrange themselves.

Comment: I never said there's no other way.  And if videos are rearranging themselves, then either you have a virus or some setting is not set correctly.  If you could clarify your question with some screenshots of what is happening, it might help you get a better answer.

Comment: I think I might understand what's happening now.  You probably have your folder set to icon view. You'll want to set it to Details view.  Within the folder, press Alt-V then D for Details.  Then you can click any of the columns to sort by that column. It sounds to me that your files are simply not named in sequential order, and the folder is automatically sorting them by name when you re-open it.